# No route matches the route I had just created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Good morning!

I'm lost as to how my route isn't found for a route I had *just* created in `routes.rb`. When I load `localhost:3000/Manage/Delete/1` I'm thrown a `No route matches [GET] "/Manage/Delete/1"` message. This doesn't make sense because I have clearly defined it in `routes.rb`:

```
# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
root 'welcome#index'

# Example of regular route:
get 'Portfolio' => 'my_work#index'
get 'Posts/:id' => 'posts#with_id'
get 'Contact' => 'contact#index'
get 'Contacted' => 'contact#contacted'
get 'Manage' => 'manage#index'
get 'Manage/Create' => 'manage#create'
get 'Manage/Delete/:id' => 'manage#delete'
get '404' => 'problems#_404'
get '422' => 'problems#_422'
get '500' => 'problems#_500'

post 'Contact' => 'contact#send_message'

# Problem pages
match '/404', to: 'problems#_404', via: :all
match '/422', to: 'problems#_422', via: :all
match '/500', to: 'problems#_500', via: :all
```

I've done everything from restarting my server to making sure I was in the development environment and I'm still running into this issue. I *do* have a view for it, I *do* have a method for it in my controller (it's just an empty method), and I *do* have the route. Here's what happens in the log when I load the page:

```
Started GET "/Manage/Delete/1" for ::1 at 2015-07-25 08:54:34 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Manage/Delete/1"):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:490:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:361:in `process_client'
  puma (2.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
  puma (2.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `call'
  puma (2.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:92:in `block in spawn_thread'


  Rendered /Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (56.3ms)
```

...and `bundle exec rake routes`:

```
       Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
         root GET  /                        welcome#index
    Portfolio GET  /Portfolio(.:format)     my_work#index
              GET  /Posts/:id(.:format)     posts#with_id
      Contact GET  /Contact(.:format)       contact#index
    Contacted GET  /Contacted(.:format)     contact#contacted
       Manage GET  /Manage(.:format)        manage#index
Manage_Create GET  /Manage/Create(.:format) manage#create
   Manage_Bye GET  /Manage/Bye(.:format)    manage#bye
Manage_Logout GET  /Manage/Logout(.:format) manage#logout
              GET  /404(.:format)           problems#_404
              GET  /422(.:format)           problems#_422
              GET  /500(.:format)           problems#_500
              POST /Contact(.:format)       contact#send_message
              POST /Manage(.:format)        manage#index
              POST /Manage/Create(.:format) manage#create
              POST /Manage/Logout(.:format) manage#logout
                   /404(.:format)           problems#_404
                   /422(.:format)           problems#_422
                   /500(.:format)           problems#_500
```

`routes.rb` as seen in nano:

[image: <code>routes.rb</code> as seen in nano]

Comment: Can you post the output of the console for this command? `bundle exec rake routes`

Comment: As you can see, there is no route for the /Manage/Delete/:id. Are you sure you posted the last version of your routes.rb?

Comment: That's the version I had edited and saved with Coda. I thought for whatever reason Coda didn't actually write out the file, but after opening it with nano in Terminal I've verified that the file has been overwritten with the route. Why wouldn't this route be in the result of `bundle exec rake routes` when I've defined it in `routes.rb`?

Comment: I think that the routes.rb is not saved. What does the `cat config/routes.rb` give?

Comment: Deleting objects should *not* be done via a `GET` route. Please read up on resource routing in Rails - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: @sevenseacat I know. I'm working on that! Thank you for warning me.

Comment: @LazarusLazaridis `routes.rb` wasn't saved. I was editing a file called `routes.rb` within `/` rather than `config`. I don't know how that was there or how I didn't remember it was supposed to be in the `config` dir. Thank you so much for helping me! Write that last comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are editing a `routes.rb` file which is somehow not the one to be edited (`config/routes.rb`)

As @sevenseacat mentioned though, check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default for some guidelines on the proper way of defining your routes.